# How do I go about designing a form for 960x540 resolution?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have an application that I am in the middle of development for, and I never took into account the fact that some users may be running their machines at a lower resolution than mine. I can't change the resolution on my machine as it only puts out 1680x1050. Since I've ever only developed applications for myself, I've never thought about the whole resolution aspect of development, so I wouldn't even know where to begin. Unfortunately, I am tied down to VS2005 with the .NET 2.0 framework and MUST use it. Any help towards how to go about starting this would be great, thanks!

Comment: You start working on it.  You resize your window and look at your UI. You use container controls that properly resize their children to the available window size. You set a minimum and don't support less. You get visual studio 2013 honestly, why are you using a ten year old development tool to do this?

Comment: This does tend to be discovered the Hard Way.  Simple workarounds are setting the form's AutoScale property to True so it is still somewhat usable and you changing the form's Font property to a smaller font.

Comment: It's weird that you cant' lower the resolution of your own screen... wrong drivers perhaps? Anyway you can always create a virtual machine and set it up to any resolution you'll need to test your program at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

960x540 is a fairly ridiculously old resolution to be supporting, but you can achieve what I think you're wanting simply enough.

Go to your designer, click on the form. In the `Properties` pane, change the `Size` option to whatever minimum resolution you're trying to support, e.g.: 950, 530

I would recommend, however, that you simply use the above direction for design purposes, so you don't create controls that are off the screen or require scrollbars. What you should *also* do is set the `WindowState` to `Maximized`, what way it will always just fill their screen. In most cases, I believe this is a wise route as most end-users barely know how to browse the internet.

Comment: Thanks, I've found that this is something best learned through trial and error as opposed to reading. Everyone's tips did help, and in the end I achieved the size I needed. Thanks again.